# Does the inverse function theorem provide a path to interpretation of more general infinitesimal quotients?

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, notation, infinitesimals

Let us first bring up ***inverse function theorem*** : If $y=f(x)$ and if $f'(x)$ exists at some point $x=a$, then exists in some neighborhood of $(a,f(a))$ an inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ which around corresponding $b = f(a)$, such that it is differentiable and that this differential fulfills:

$$(f^{-1})'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(a)}$$

Could this bring a fruitful approach to define the reciprocal infinitesimal quotient below:

$$\frac{\partial f^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}(b) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial f(x)}(a)$$

Would it lead to anything meaningful, or will we run into trouble if we would try to do so?

---

For context : My mind wanders to some example $$\frac{\partial \sin(t)}{\partial \cos(t)}$$ which in polar coordinates $x = \cos(t), y = \sin(t)$ and trigonometric identity could be intuitively interpreted as the differential of the function describing the upper part of unit circle:

$$\frac{\partial \sqrt{1-x^2}}{\partial x}$$

Some far fetched but interesting try would be to extend to find meaning and interpretation to things like $$\frac{\partial g(t)}{\partial h(t)}$$

Answer (score 1):

If we stick with $\mathrm d$ rather than $\partial$, then there's little problem with handling single-variable in this sort of way. We define $\mathrm d (f(t))=f'(t)\mathrm dt$ (and similarly for any other variable), and then the algebra works out nicely for first-order derivatives.

For example:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\sin t}{\mathrm{d}\cos t}=\dfrac{\cos t\,\mathrm{d}t}{-\sin t\,\mathrm{d}t}=-\cot t\text{.}$$
And we also have, if $t\in[0,\pi]$ and we let $x=\cos t$:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\sin t}{\mathrm{d}\cos t}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{-2x\,\mathrm dx}{2\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}=\dfrac{-\cos t}{\sin t}=-\cot t\text{.}$$

Now, there could be trouble with second-order derivatives, but there is also a fix for this (basically, don't write a second derivative as $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx\vphantom{)}^2}$ if $x$ and $y$ could depend on some other variable $t$). Details are discussed in the recently-popular-on-the-internet paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials" by Bartlett and Khurshudyan. One version can be found on the arXiv at [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09553) and another is on the site for the journal "Dynamics of Continuous, Discrete and Impulsive Systems" [here](http://online.watsci.org/contents2019/v26n3a.html).

Comment: Hmm. Not sure I follow. Will try read later.